# function to transfer count number of characters from source string to destination string from right

Tags: c

I have written this function to transfer count number of characters from source string to destination string from right. I am passing string to src, NULL to dst and the count value to function

If i send input string as "Stack overflow" and count as 4 i want the o/p string as "flow". But here my o/p string is always empty, can u pls tell what is wrong in my logic. pls

```
char *Rprint(const char *src, char *dst, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *ret = NULL;
    while(*src!= '\0')
        src++;
    dst = malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
    ret = dst;
    dst = dst + (count + 1);
    while(count)
    {
        *dst++ = *src--;
        count--;
    }
    *dst++ = '\0';
    //return ret;
    printf("String:%s \n", ret);

}
```

Comment: you set 'dst' one past the end of alloc'd buffer, and then increment ...! That's not good...

Answer (score 0):

I expect you meant to do this:

```
*dst-- = *src--;
```

I don't like the way you are doing this, but that should get you on track without me suggesting that you completely rewrite your code.

You should not null-terminate the string afterwards, because you have already copied the terminator.  You are copying your string from the end to the beginning (*ie* reverse-copy), but confusing it with the more usual forward-copy.

Be careful with your loop condition.  You might have an off-by-one error there.  Same with adding `count+1` to `dst`.  I think you should only add `count`.

Oh, and don't forget to return a value from your function!

Comment: i in the while loop i did *dst-- = *src-- and before entering the while loop i did dst = dst + count +1; and did *dst = '\0' initially itself i am taking care to end the sting with '\0' but still i just get a blank o/p

Comment: No.  `src` is already sitting on the `'\0'` character.  That will be the first to be copied.  It should go in at `dst+count`, *not* `dst+count+1`.

Comment: sorry i understood what u told as i dont need to NULL terminate the string, even after doing tht i am still not able to get any o/p

Comment: Look, you're going to have to debug your code.  You have selected an unintuitive way to copy your string, and unless you get every part of it correct, you're probably going to have an empty or invalid result.  Try printing out every character individually from `ret` to `ret+count`, and you'll soon work out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code , based on your original approach , but with few corrections.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Rprint(const char [], char [], int );


int main()
{
char buff[50] = "stack overflow";
char cut [50];

Rprint(buff,cut,5);
puts(cut);
}


void Rprint(const char src[], char dst[], int count)
{

    while(*src!= '\0')
       src++;

    src = src - count;

    while(count--)
        *(dst++) = *(src++);

    *(dst++) = '\0';

}
```